# Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/

Tags: eclipse, repository

I have read and researched this issue through stackoverflow and other sites to no avail. I am stuck and would like to know if anyone has a definitive answer,

I have downloaded and tried "installing new software" for eclipse mars, juno and kepler - all with the same result (unable to read...).

I have turned off firewall and disabled anti-virus.

I have been able to download repositories from other sites (listed as default in the combobox for available sites) - just not the respositories for the above versions.

I have various versions of eclipse (on various machines and platforms too) to manage Android, Java and Python (and have never had a problem with the repositories). Each version is physically separate.

I am using Vista Ultimate on a home network - so no proxy issues.

I have tried changing the ini file for -vmargs again to no avail. I have tried deleting and reloading the repository.

The best answer I have read so far was that "it suddenly started working again" leading me to believe that the problem is at Eclipse's end.

Is there something I have missed or have not tried?

All I want is an Eclipse based Javascript editor!

Comment: Have you tried to get to http://download.eclipse.org/releases/ with a web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release repository is specific to the release of Eclipse, for Eclipse Mars it is `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars` This should already be in your Available Software Sites list.